# Permissions to run Custom audit log report on SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-permissions, audit-log-reports

My client has an on-prem Sharepoint 2016 and wants to run their own audit log report - they want to see who accessed a certain folder within a certain period.  As normal user, they to  not see the Audit log report option under site settings, but me as a farm admin can see it.  Which permission do I need to give them to be able to see that option and select the report to run? (I do not really want to add the user as a farm admin just to be able to run their own audit log report)

Comment: Do not confuse a farm administrator with a site collection administrator. Farm admins do not have full access to site collections by default. So, to view audit reports they should be site collection admins, not farm admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They need at least full control permission level (site collection administrator) to view audit log report option under site settings.